# Node.js: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: javascript, node.js

I keep getting this message when I'm trying to connect to localhost:3000 (Visual Studio Code, Node JS). I am not sure how to correct this.Edit: I corrected my file to server.js but I am still getting the same message. Any help is appreciated[image: enter image description here!]

Here is my code for server.js

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

let initial_path = path.join(__dirname, "public");

const app = express();
app.use(express.static(initial_path));

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(initial_path, "home.html"));
})

app.listen("3000", () => {
    console.log('listening......');
})
```

And my code for package.json

```
{
  "name": "bloggin-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon server.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express-fileupload": "^1.2.1",
    "express.js": "^1.0.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.15"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "description": ""
}
```

Comment: Rename `servor.js` to `server.js`. Spot the difference? Also, move `server.js` _out_ of the `public` folder/directory.

Comment: @code thanks! I changed the name and my server.js file is out of the public folder and under Final but I am getting the same message. Any tips?

Comment: Do you get this error when you run `node server.js` or `npm run start`? The reason this error occurs is because the file is non-existent (likely because it's being referenced incorrectly).

Comment: I get it when I run npm start

Comment: Having changed the location of you file, you might want to double check your paths too.

Comment: What does your file structure look like now? (Can you edit your answer?)

Answer (score 2):

It's going to be a lot of little error like this as you learn. Try to slow down and read. Your filename is servor.js
[image]

Answer (score 2):

rename `servor.js` to `server.js`. I faced a lot when I am learning programming)
Good luck bro keep it up!